# How to create the smallest possible number remaining zeros?

Tags: python

I was given a task to create the smallest number from two numbers remaining zeros.
But I cannot solve the task because of my code is not remaining all zeros appropriate. If the input is

```
245
36
```

the output is 23456 and that's correct. But with input:

```
40
305
```

it outputs: `[0,0,3,4,5]`. But should be `30045`.

Here's my code:

```
f1 = [int(x) for x in input()]
f2 = [int(y) for y in input()]
f = f1+f2
for each in range(len(f)):
    for eacc in range(each+1, len(f)):
        if f[each] > f[eacc]:
            f[each], f[eacc] = f[eacc], f[each]
for zero in range(len(f)):
    if f[zero] == 0 and f[0] > 0:
        f.remove(0)
        f.insert(zero+1, 0)
        break
print(f)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "create the smallest number from two numbers remaining zeros"?

Comment: My guess is "find the lexicographically smallest digit sequence that does not start with a zero". 00345 doesn't qualify because it starts with a zero. 30045 qualifies because it does not start with a zero.

Comment: @user2357112 so the output should start with digit that's more than 0

Comment: I think you may mean "containing" rather than "remaining" but it still produces ambiguous phrases

Answer (score 0):

```
n1 = 40
n2 = 305

# sort lexicograhically
ns = sorted(str(n1) + str(n2))

# move the first non-zero element to the start
i = ns.count('0')
if 0 < i < len(ns):
    ns[0:0] = ns.pop(i)
```

Comment: Short. Would it be shorter if you use a function that returns the last index of a character in a string?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the zeros. Get all the [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and find the min. Then add zero from index 1

```
from itertools import permutations
a=list('40')+list('305')
a=list(map(int,a))
num_of_zero=a.count(0) # get the count of zeros
for i in range(num_of_zero):
    a.pop(a.index(0))
new_list=list(min(list(permutations(a)))) # get all the permutations
for i in range(num_of_zero):
    new_list.insert(1,0) # insert zeros at index 1 shifting all element to the right

print(''.join(map(str,new_list)))#30045
```

Without permutations [sorted](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/sorted.html) will also work

```
a=list('40')+list('305')
a=list(map(int,a))
num_of_zero=a.count(0)
for i in range(num_of_zero):
    a.pop(a.index(0))
new_list=sorted(a)
for i in range(num_of_zero):
    new_list.insert(1,0)
print(''.join(map(str,new_list)))#30045
```

Using [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/user/quickstart.html)

```
import numpy as np
a=list('40')+list('305')
a=list(map(int,a))
num_of_zero=a.count(0)

new_list=sorted(a) # sorted will return [0,0,3,4,5] 

I = np.nonzero(new_list) #return non_zero_array
if(len(I[0])>0):
    first_non_zero_value=new_list.pop(I[0][0]) #get index of first element
    new_list.insert(0,first_non_zero_value)
print(''.join(map(str,new_list)))#30045
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you could use *itertools.permutations*. First I would use `map` to change the `ints` to `lists`.  Next I would concatenate  them and have one `list` of `5 ints`. Then using *permutations* we could generate all possible numbers that could be made from these `5 ints`.  From our new list we could now take the `min` using *list comprehension to filter out any item that begins with `0` using `if i[0]`. Since it is a tuple we have to convert the elements to `str` then we can `join` them into an `int` and `print`

```
from itertools import permutations

a = 40
b = 305

a = [*map(int, str(a))]
b = [*map(int, str(b))]

c = a + b

combo = list(permutations(c, len(c)))

res = min([i for i in combo if i[0]])
res = [str(i) for i in res]

print(''.join(res))
# 30045
```

If `a = 0, b = 0` is a potential input, a `try/except` block would be neccessary

```
try:
    res = min([i for i in combo if i[0]])
    res = [str(i) for i in res]
    print(int(''.join(res)))
except ValueError:
    res = 0
    print(res)
```

Comment: @mad_ going to see about that now, as well my `r` value should be based on `len(c)`

Comment: @mad_ Do you think 0/0 is a valid input seeing as we are not accepting a final answer with a leading 0 so there is never a case where 0/0 should be entered, correct?

Comment: @mad_ I could just add a `try/except ValueError` for the case of a 0/0 input but think it could be unnecessary

Comment: I see inputs as just ints. It should return something. we are neglecting the initial zero because `00345` is `345` and zero does not make sense in the start. I just like thinking about edge cases. Not necessary though.

Comment: Now try with a=1,b=0 sorry. I just want to correct the logic of yours

Comment: @mad_ no I appreciate it I need to learn, as well as sorry for being incorrect

Comment: @mad_ well its `10` wouldn't that be the smallest combination without a leading `0` since the only combinations are 01 and 10, and 01 is invalid according to OP, is this case not handled properly?

Comment: is it giving the result as `10`? It gave me a scary looking error

Comment: @mad_ `chrx@chrx:~/python/stackoverflow/10.3$ python3.7 stack.py
10`